# Click link without id using javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click

Today I'd try to click link using javascript. I don't know id, only class. Have u got any ideas ?

Thanks

Link:

```
<a class="signIn" href="#" onclick="doLogin(); return false;"/>
```

Comment: How about simply calling doLogin() directly?

Comment: Or pass this through to the click event

Answer (score 1):

use **click** or **bind** functions in jquery that will make it simple

```
$('.signIn').click(function(){
     alert('link clicked');
});
```

if you want to get the link clicked programmatic you can use $('.signIn').click();

refer
Click http://api.jquery.com/click/

and
Bind 
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 0):

if you are aware of jQuery you can do

```
jQuery(".signIn").click();
```

if not then you can try `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` it will return you an array of href elements. It will be easy for you to find your HREF if you can find it in a loop and check if its having attribute `class=signIn`.